# Is there a lua-c api function which doesn't remove the complete stack?

Tags: lua, luac

My problem is that lua_pcall clears the stack, because i want to reuse the stack before the call again with just one change again.
 Is there a way to either copy the complete stack and paste it in again or even a way to call a lua function without clearing the stack?

Lua:

```lua
function test(a)
    print(a)
end

event.add("test", test)
event.add("test", test)

event.call("test", 42)
```

C++:

```cpp
int Func_Event_call(Lua_State* L){

    //Stack: String:Eventname, Arguments...

    std::string name = luaL_checkstring(L, 1);

    ... Get array functions from name

    for(...){

        //load function into stack
        lua_rawgeti(L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX, functions[c]);
        lua_replace(L, 1);

        //Wanted Stack: Lua_Function, Arguments... <- works for the first function

        //call function
        lua_pcall(L, nummberArgs, 0, 0);

        //stack is now empty because of lua_pcall <- problem
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hi ! Could you be more clear in your explanation ? Try to edit your post and add some formatting to make your point (you didn't use line breaks or different sentences, which makes your point very difficult to understand). See you on SO ;)

Comment: What you may be looking for is to create a C function that is callable from within Lua - they receive the current stack, plus function arguments on that; or make your API receive a closure. Those can carry their own state and so it does not matter if the stack is cleared - as long as you call into the same Lua state ofc.

Comment: @dualed i updated the code sample, i have the problem that the stack is cleared from lua_pcall, i want to call multiple functions from a lua function and need a way to either store and copy the stack before the call or call the lua function without reseting the stack by lua_pcall.

Comment: I may have just realised what you're asking and have been on a totally different assumption - If you think your C++ code gets unwieldy or slow due to pushing things on the stack repeatedly, then you think wrong; Also `pcall` is not really *clearing* your function arguments from the stack, think of it as the function consuming them - this is simply how the Lua C API works. Don't mess with the stack...

Comment: @Marlonie2010 You should post your solution as an answer, instead of adding it to your question - there is nothing inherently wrong with answering your own question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```cpp
    //store stack in Registry
    lua_createtable(L, nummberArgs, nummberArgs);
    lua_insert(L, 1);

    //fill table
    for (int c = 0; c < nummberArgs; c++) {

        lua_pushinteger(L, c);
        lua_insert(L, -2);
        lua_settable(L, 1);

    }

    //store it in Registry and clean up
    int reg_key = luaL_ref(L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX);
    lua_remove(L, 1);

    ...

    //restore stack from above
    lua_rawgeti(L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX, reg_key);

    //iterate over the table to get all elements, the key is getting removed by lua_next
    lua_pushnil(L);
    while (lua_next(L, 1) != 0) {
        /* uses 'key' (at index -2) and 'value' (at index -1) */
        /* move 'value'; keeps 'key' for next iteration */
        lua_insert(L, -2);
    }

    //remove table from stack
    lua_remove(L, 1);
```

I solved the problem by using a table in the registry and put the complete stack in the table with numeric keys. After calling the second part i can go back to the stack when the first part was called, but multiple times.